# Creating and sending raw IP packets in FreeBSD - sendto() error Invalid Argument

Tags: c, sockets, freebsd, packets

My goal is to create an IP Packet with just headers and no payload.
I am using http://www.enderunix.org/docs/en/rawipspoof/ as a guide. 
The current issue is that I cannot appease sendto() and I'm not sure how to get more verbose feedback on which parameter is invalid and how it is invalid.

Running `truss` on my program;

```
sendto(3,"E\0\0\^T2\^^\0\0@\M^?\0\0\^?\0\0"...,20,0x0,{ AF_INET 127.0.0.1:1337 },0x10) ERR#22 'Invalid argument'
```

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <netinet/in_systm.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int    sockfd;
  const int on = 1;
  struct sockaddr_in tx; 
  struct ip pkt_hdr; 
  u_char *pkt; 

  //Init IP packet header fields
  pkt_hdr.ip_hl  = 0x5; // 5 x 32 bit length units
  pkt_hdr.ip_v   = 0x4; // IPv4 type packet
  pkt_hdr.ip_tos = 0x0; // ?? Type of Service, packet precedence ???
  pkt_hdr.ip_len = htons(20); // Total Length of Packet
  pkt_hdr.ip_id  = htons(12830); // Packet ID
  pkt_hdr.ip_off = 0x0; // Set fragment offset to 0, don't want fragmentation
  pkt_hdr.ip_ttl = 64; // TTL in number of hops
  pkt_hdr.ip_p   = IPPROTO_RAW; // Protocol
  pkt_hdr.ip_sum = 0x0; // No checksum

  pkt_hdr.ip_src.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  pkt_hdr.ip_dst.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  //Copy header packet 
  pkt = (u_char *)malloc(20);
  memcpy(pkt, &pkt_hdr, sizeof(pkt_hdr));    

  //Open raw socket as the intended output write 
  //destination for a IP packet 
  if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0 )
  {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  //Tell kernel to not prepare IP header
  if (setsockopt(sockfd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_HDRINCL,&on,sizeof(on)))
  {
    perror("setsockop"); 
    exit(1);
  }

  //Init network IP information  
  //for routing and transmission
  //so kernel can prepare layer 1 data 
  memset(&tx, 0, sizeof(tx));
  tx.sin_family      = AF_INET;
  tx.sin_port        = htons(1337);
  tx.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 

  //Write the packet out to the network pipe
  if (sendto(sockfd, pkt, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&tx,sizeof(tx)) < 0 )
  {
    perror("sendto");
    exit(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see you calculating the IP header checksum. I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.  Two other minor code-review type stuff. You don't need to call "malloc", just assign `pkt = (u_char*)&pkt_hdr;` . As you have it now, your code leaks 20 bytes of memory on each call.

Comment: Also read the following links: http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw  Looks like BSD has lots of nuances.

Comment: removing the "malloc" causes a segfault, fyi

Answer (score 1):

The problem with my code was that it wasn't complying with the FreeBSD kernel. I asked this same [question in the FreeBSD forums](http://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=44058&sid=c2ad56c6e4fa2bc2fe5fa276f21f6964) where it was pointed out that I need to supply the `ip.len` and `ip.off` values in host-byte order as opposed to network byte order, and the endianess of the values was what `sock()` was complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me on my Linux machine.

The only issue I can think of is SOCK_RAW. Are you privileged enough to use it? I have to run it with `sudo`, when I ran as a normal user it gave me `socket: Operation not permitted`.

This is a blind guess, but maybe your implementation fails to fail on

`sockfd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)`?

If you've verified it I'll remove this answer not to cause confusion ;-)

Comment: Everything's being executed with SUID 0 as root at the moment during initial development, so nope. Thanks though! Which linux kernel and distro are you using? Guess I'll have to jump ship from BSD for this one.

Comment: Verified on Kubuntu with 3.5.0 and Gentoo@3.12.6. It's very strange, if you'd find the answer please post it, I find it very interesting.